# Django form not displaying with Multiple forms rendered to a template in a single view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a view which renders 2 forms to a template, but only one renders, the other doesnt display and it doesnt give me any error, but I can see that the form display when I print it in my console.

This is my model for the form not showing

```py
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

This is the model for the admin, Im inheriting from AbstractUSer

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

This is the form for the model

```py
class OrganizationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        fields = ['name']
```

This is the form for the Admin

```py
class AdminSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email']


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_admin = True
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

This is the view which I am calling the multiple forms

```py
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        adminForm = AdminSignUpForm(request.POST)
        orgForm = OrganizationForm(request.POST)
        if adminForm.is_valid() and orgForm.is_valid():
            adminForm.save()
            orgForm.save(commit=False)
            username = adminForm.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = adminForm.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('myapp:home')
    else:

        adminForm = AdminSignUpForm()
        orgForm = OrganizationForm()

    print(orgForm)
    return render(request, 'registration/signup_form.html', {'OrgFrom': orgForm,'Adminform': adminForm})
```

And this is the template I am rendering the multiple forms

```html
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" >
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">


        {{Adminform.as_p }}
        {{ OrgForm.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign up</button>
      </form>
```

I expect both forms to be displayed but only the Adminform displays and it gives me no error to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one typo. You need to use `{{ OrgFrom.as_p }}` instead of `{{ Orgform.as_p }}`.

Comment: so AdminSignUpForm is not rendering?

Comment: The AdminSignUpForm is showing up, like I said in my question its only the OrganizationForm that isnt showing

Comment: In that case, you still have that typo in your html. You are trying to do `{{ OrgForm.as_p }}` but from your view, you are sending `OrgFrom` in the context.

Comment: I doubt that is the problem as the .as_p is just an extension to render the form in p tags despite it works for the AdminForm

Comment: how can you access OrgForm when its not there in the context?

Comment: Im not sure whether you read thriugh the question or you are probably new to django but this is it passed to the template {'OrgFrom': orgForm,'Adminform': adminForm}

Comment: Mehn I have solved cant imagine I skipped the typo, thanks alot